# How to reaplace collect function in pyspark to lambda and map

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, pagerank

I have a function that generates the graph of internal Wikipedia links.
in the code, I use the collect function in pyspark but when I use the same code in GCP it doesn't work.
I was told to change the collect function that I used in the code to lambda and map expression.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean map as the built-in function or pyspark map?

Comment: doesn't matter, any of them

Answer (score 1):

.map in pyspark works similar to regular map, i.e.

```
list_of_vertices = pages.map(lambda it:it.anchor_text.id)
```

and

```
list_of_edges = pages.map(lambda it: Row(src=it.id, dst=it.anchor_text.id))
```

Comment: it raise an error "'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable" (pages)

Comment: That probably stems from trying to iterate over it. Updated the example to not use a for-loop.

Comment: thats work well but how i do that for the edges, if I need to map the Row

Comment: Added an example for edges also, not entirely sure if it works with the Row-objects

Comment: i need to return edges and vertices, the map doesn't create a list so I cant parallelize it, I mean when I try to return the edges and the vertic it doesn't work well

Comment: The function .parallelize takes a list and creates a RDD, while .collect does the opposite. An idea would be to use neither, and skip the transformations between list and RDD entirely.

Comment: But i have to return RDD for each one of them, RDD of edge. and RDD of vertices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239881/discussion-between-maor-biton-and-olav-aga).